# How to block HTTP and HTTPS ports in Skype for OS X

Tags: macos, skype, http, https

How I can configure Skype on OSX to not use port 80?

In the Windows version of Skype, you can configure the main port (80 by default) and the alternative (443 by default).

**Windows Options**

[image]

However, on OSX there does not seem to be this same option - how can I access and change these options on Mac?

**EDIT 1**

@nerdwaller Thanks for editing! Great job!

I want to use nginx and Skype blocks this ports.

Comment: "There is good option for Windows version, but there I can't find any in version for Skype."  What?  Is there an option in skype for Windows but not in skype for OSX, is that what you are getting at?

Comment: @nerdwaller Sure. In skype for windows you have 'Use port 80 and 443 as alternative', I can't find it in skype for mac.

Comment: Unless this option is exposed in the interface you can't reconfigure Skype.

Comment: @Ramhound Dual-instance also not exposed anywhere in the gui.

Comment: Updated your answer, in the future - you should respond to questions by [updating your post](http://superuser.com/posts/641373/edit).  I tried to clear up the ambiguity as well.

Comment: @JevgeniSmirnov - Whats your point?

Answer (score 1):

I just downloaded the most recent version of Skype on OSX 10.8.4 - I see the option under "Advanced", while I can't define alternatives (the 80/443 option in the screenshot from Windows) - it sounds like you want to block those anyway...  So that doesn't seem to be an issue from my understanding.

[image]